# Is it possible to restrict /tmp to 0770 permissions?

Tags: file-sharing, users

I would like to prevent 2 non-root users on the same Linux system from sharing files with each other (via their use of /tmp). Is this possible somehow?

If I restrict `/tmp` to `0770` (`root:root` as the owner:group) and define a user-specific `TMPDIR` via an `export TMPDIR=~/tmp; mkdir -p $TMPDIR` early on in the boot process (say, via an `rc[35].d` script), then GConf2 starts having problems. A typical error I then get is:

`/usr/libexec/gconf-sanity-check-2 exited with status 256`

Everything seems to work fine in Run Level 3 (non GUI)... though I could be wrong in concluding this prematurely, and problems could surface later in Run Level 3 as well.

My experience so far with `TMPDIR` seems to indicate that it is either broken, or is not sufficiently documented, or is not being embraced by all Gnome applications.

Answer (score 4):

This would be an extremely bad idea.  It violates an extremely widespread (pervasive) and long-standing (as in "from time immemorial") set of assumptions that's likely to be ingrained in a great many applications and utilities.

You'd be far better to create chroot jails or virtual subsystems and confine these users thereby rather than trying to simply lock them out of ***/tmp***.

**TMPDIR** is only a convention, not a standard.  UNIX/Linux programs are free to honor or not at the whims of their authors and maintainers.

Comment: I read the `chroot` INFO page, not sure how I would go about making all those 1000s of binaries available under a new root, and that too for each separate user. Would appreciate any further pointers, if you have done this before. Tia,

Comment: Unfortunately chroot jails are rather complex and not particularly popular.  Additionally they aren't 100% effective as a security measure under certain versions of UNIX/Linux or certain conditions (such as if the same filesystem is mounted under multiple different chroot environments using --bind or similar features).  It's even more difficult if your goal is to support and isolated multiple GUI users on the same host.  At some point it makes far more sense to create a new VM (virtual machine) for each ... or just give them each their own workstation.

Answer (score 3):

Bad idea as others pointed out. You can use ACLs to get similar result:

```
groupadd tmpdir-denied
setfacl -m g:tmpdir-denied:- /tmp    # the specific group has no access to /tmp
getfacl /tmp                         # see permissions
```

Don't get me wrong. The ACL **will break things** too, if not now then in future, but the impact will be hopefully somewhat limited. I would test as a minimum if I can still (1) backup (2) restore (3) patch system after these changes.

Comment: Thanks. But can you also tell me how to undo the effect of the above? Basically, I want to be able to get back the original `'.'` character (denoting default SELinux context) in the output of`ls -ld /tmp`. After issuing your commands, I'm seeing a `'+'` character, and am not sure how to get it back.

Comment: My memory failed, I would need to check it in `man`. In the meantime let me ask you, is my answer worth an upvote/accept or not?

Comment: Yes, surely :-). I was thinking of upvoting a little bit later, as my mind was totally totally preoccupied with the problem. Here you go, my friend...

Comment: Great. To remove `setfacl -x g:nobody /tmp` or to remove all ACLs `setfacl -b /tmp`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a good idea to change the `/tmp` permissions. Many applications create files temporary under `/tmp` and they are not running necessarily under root privileges. So, you will break them if you do so.